# Find the number of $8$-digit numbers $ABCDEFGH$ with distinct digits from $1$ to $8$ such that $A > B > C > D$ and $D < E < F < G < H$.

Tags: combinatorics

Combinatorial problem from [Quizlet](https://quizlet.com/568026712/math-assessment-flash-cards/):

> Find the number of $8$-digit numbers $ABCDEFGH$ with distinct digits from
> $1$ to $8$ such that $A > B > C > D$ and $D < E < F < G < H$.

I found this problem very interesting and have an idea to solve it, but my method is very long. I wonder whether my answer is correct and whether there exist a "better" way to solve it (more shorter or elegant).

---

My attempt: $D\in\{2,1\}$.

1. For $D=2$, $H\in\{6,7,8,9\}$.

Let $H=6$, then $ABCDEFGH=98723456$ is the only option.

Let $H=7$, then $ABCDEFGH\in\{98623457,98523467,98423567,98324567\}$, so $4$ options. Another way of looking at it: For $EFG$ we will have ${4 \choose 3}$, and for one integer not chosen for $EFG$ will combine with $8,9$ to form $ABC$, i.e., ${3 \choose 3}$. In the end ${4 \choose 3}\times {3 \choose 3}=4$.

Let $H=8$, then ${5 \choose 3}$ for $EFG$, and ${3 \choose 3}$ for $ABC$, then ${5 \choose 3}\times {3 \choose 3}=10$ options.

Let $H=9$, then ${6 \choose 3}$ for $EFG$, and ${3 \choose 3}$ for $ABC$, then ${6 \choose 3}\times {3 \choose 3}=20$ options.

In total $35$ options when $D=2$.

2. For $D=1$, following the same logic:

$\Big({3 \choose 3}+{4 \choose 3}+{5 \choose 3}+{6 \choose 3}+{7 \choose 3}\Big)\times {4 \choose 3}=280$ options. Here "$\times {4 \choose 3}$" is for $ABC$ combination.

In the end, I got $315$ combinations in total.

Comment: It says that the digits are from $1$ to $8$? Why is $D$ equal to $0,1,2$?

Comment: @UmeshShankar it is my mistake, I will edit my answer

Comment: Why is $D=2$ allowed? Your number is an $8$ digit number and the allowed digits are $1$ to $8$.

Comment: "98723456"? "digits from $1$ t $8$"?

Comment: Yes, it is because I counted $0$ and $9$, which is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$D=1$ since every other position is the "greater" side of some inequality. After this, specifying $\{A,B,C\}$ completely determines the number since there is only one way to arrange any set of numbers on either side of $D$ (we have two total orders); thus the answer is $\binom73=35$.

Comment: thanks, I should have not count $9$